# How to change buttons font color with vcl styles?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles, jedi

I'm styling a form changing the font color of a TSpeedButton, but my application uses VCL Styles and that overrides the color I set on design time. Has anyone experienced this and know any way to achieve it? Change the component is not a problem, I've tried using TButton, TSpeedButton, TJvSpeedButton (from JEDI) but none of them kept the color I set.

Using Delphi XE2, the property StyleElements is not available.

Answer (score 2):

All VCL controls have a property `StyleElements` in which you can disable `seFont` to override the style's font and put your own.

Comment: thats for XE3 or later

Comment: @CarlosM Really? Then you can either modify the style (which would change all button font colors), or upgrade your Delphi, since XE2 is kinda old.